# Test createRoot().render() using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a custom theme I am adding as in the code below:

```
//main.tsx
import App from "./app/lib/App";
import { ThemeProvider } from "./core";
import { MyThemeProvider} from "./MyThemeProvider";
import { themeRegistries} from "./ThemeProviders/themeRegistries";

const domNode = document.getElementById("root");
createRoot(domNode).render(
  <ThemeProvider themeName={"CompanyDefaultTheme"}>
    <MyThemeProvider
      applicationName="My Custom Application Name"
      scopeName="My application scope"
      themeName="MyCustomTheme"
      themeRegistries={[themeRegistries]}
    >
       <App />
    </MyThemeProvider>
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```

My plan to test it is to load the component and find the component with the `My Custom Application Name` and verify it exists in the DOM.

```
//main.spec.tsx
/// <reference types="jest" />
import React from "react";
import { screen } from "@testing-library/react";

jest.mock("react-dom", () => {
  jest.fn();
});

describe("Application root", () => {
  it("should render without crashing", async () => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "root";
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    require("./main");
    const component = await screen.findByText("My Custom Application Name");
    expect(component).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

My test fails with the below error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED')

      2 | import React from "react";
    > 3 | import { screen } from "@testing-library/react";
        | ^
      4 |
      5 | jest.mock("react-dom", () => {
      6 |   jest.fn();

      at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:1125:32
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:1740:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/test-utils.js:6:20)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/.pnpm/@testing-library+react@13.4.0_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:10:41)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/.pnpm/@testing-library+react@13.4.0_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/index.js:7:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/main.spec.tsx:4:1)
```

I am not really experienced with testing libraries like jest. How can I confirm `MyThemeProvider` was loaded?

Comment: I suggest: don't. Not at this level, anyway - have some tests that the whole app starts up and can be used in a browser (Playwright, Cypress, Selenium, etc.).

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. How can I add a test which would load the main.tsx and verify it is started up?

Comment: If it didn't then _any_ E2E test, using the tools mentioned above, would fail. Try to match what would happen in production, e.g. build the app and serve the outputs: https://github.com/textbook/abv/blob/a984d8d51260523f58525033e8c0c42688e0c0d5/package.json#L35